# Как сохранить параллельность боковых граней с окном при 3D повороте?

Tags: html, css

есть задача повернуть правый блок до состояния левого:
[image]

Перепробовал всё, что знал, вплоть до Пифагора и теоремы косинусов
Не получается сделать поворот АДАПТИВНЫМ
Я могу подогнать значения под конкретное разрешение экрана (если поворачивать через rotate3D), но вывести единую формулу не получается
Подскажите пожалуйста, как такое можно реализовать?

Comment: Может вам нужен skew? https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/skew()

Comment: странно, при добавлении skew слетают все масштабы, что ширина что высота

Comment: В итоге все равно добиться нужного поворота (как на картинке) не удалось